# The same code works in one project and doesn't work in another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a project, which has a static table view. This table view has three sections and each of them has different number of rows. I'm using a code, which allows to select different rows on different sections at the same time, but not to select two different rows from the same section. Here is the code:

```
switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = true
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
        case 1:
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = true
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
        case 2:
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = true
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
        case 3:
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            fourDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = true
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            twoDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            threeDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.accessoryType = .none
            oneDollarRestaurantCell.isSelected = false
        default:
            break

        }
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            within500MetersCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            within500MetersCell.isSelected = true
            within1000MetersCell.accessoryType = .none
            within1000MetersCell.isSelected = false


        case 1:
            within1000MetersCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            within1000MetersCell.isSelected = true
            within500MetersCell.accessoryType = .none
            within500MetersCell.isSelected = false

        default:
            break
        }
    case 2:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            sortByFromAtoZCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            sortByFromAtoZCell.isSelected = true
            sortByFromZtoACell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByFromZtoACell.isSelected = false
            sortByDistanceCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByDistanceCell.isSelected = false
            sortByPriceCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByPriceCell.isSelected = false
        case 1:
            sortByFromZtoACell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            sortByFromZtoACell.isSelected = true
            sortByFromAtoZCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByFromAtoZCell.isSelected = false
            sortByDistanceCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByDistanceCell.isSelected = false
            sortByPriceCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByPriceCell.isSelected = false
        case 2:
            sortByDistanceCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            sortByDistanceCell.isSelected = true
            sortByFromZtoACell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByFromZtoACell.isSelected = false
            sortByFromAtoZCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByFromAtoZCell.isSelected = false
            sortByPriceCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByPriceCell.isSelected = false
        case 3:
            sortByPriceCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            sortByPriceCell.isSelected = true
            sortByFromZtoACell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByFromZtoACell.isSelected = false
            sortByDistanceCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByDistanceCell.isSelected = false
            sortByFromAtoZCell.accessoryType = .none
            sortByFromAtoZCell.isSelected = false

        default:
            break
        }

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Here I check the sections, and inside of them, I check each row. This was working fine, but suddenly it stopped.

**EDITED**

The expected result is the following:

[image]

The actual result is the following:

[image]

I haven't changed anything inside of that class. The same code still works in another project, so I'm desperate, because I can't understand what could cause the issue. I've tried everything, even copying the file from the working project to this project (the structure of files is exactly the same). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If this code works in another project, probably the problem is in the configuration of your table view. Provide more details about the table view, expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: +1 I echo Kamil statements. For example, if using Storyboard, have you connected your tableView outlets in your viewcontroller file with the same name as your previous project?

Comment: @LouisLeung, yes, all files have the same names as in the first project.

Comment: @KamilSzostakowski, I have added to my question the expected result and the actual result. My table view is just a simple static table view. I haven't change anything inside of that file. It was working fine in both of the projects. Then, in on of the projects it started to act like in the example above. So, that is the reason why I'm so confused. I tried to copy the entire file from the working project to that one, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Is the problem that the multiple selection doesn't work? You can set the selection attribute of the tablew view to "multiple selection"

Comment: @KamilSzostakowski, thanks. Your suggestion along with my code works great. However, there is still a little question. I've checked and in my old project selection of the table view is set to "Single selection", but it works fine. Any ideas how that could be?

Comment: Maybe it's set up somewhere  in code. I posted the answer with a bit more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main difference is the tint color of the tables that can be changed from any way! the default is blue that you have changed it to white by accident or for changing something else in your app.just set up it again to blue.

Comment: The difference is not only in tint color, but how cells from different sections behave when they are tapped. The reason, why my checkmark's color is white, is because I've set the default tint color of the project to white

Comment: so i can't see the difference of the behavior because of the tint.

Comment: Now, I understand what you are asking. Never mind, it works fine now. I just thought that something was broken, but then I realise that the reason was the tint color.

Comment: The site doesn't allow me to delete the question, so I can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the main difference between the examples you have provided is the multiple selection. To enable this feature for a `UITableView` you can set a value of the `selection` attribute to `multiple selection` in the attribute inspector.

You can also overwrite this parameter by setting the `allowsMultipleSelection` property to `true`. I'm not entirely sure but I suspect that in your first project this property is set up in code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Honestly speaking, I haven't found that code, but anyway. Also, by setting that parameter to true, I get another behaviour for free (deselection of cells when typing on them twice). Without that, I would have to write that functionality on my own. However, I still think that there is another reason why I can choose multiple cells on my first project, because there I don't have the deselection behaviour for free. It is quite strange, because as far as I can compare, the code and attributes of table views are identical.

Comment: Another option is the `accessoryType` property of the `UITablewViewCell` set to `.checkmark`. This approach won't even require the multiple selection to work if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes. In the old project, my `accessoryType` is set to `.checkmark` and `allowsMultipleSelection` property is set to false (I haven't found the code where I set it, so I think, I haven't done that programmatically).